# Does CD/DVD Writer get worn out over time?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc

I have a CD/DVD writer bought about 3 years ago. While I was able to burn any discs without issues previously, now it's having a hard time burning discs even at the lowest settings. Does the laser wear out over time that I need to purchase a new writer periodically?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes CD/DVD ROMs/Writers fail randomly, there is no part which breaks in particular, it can be the motor, it can be the small circuit, it can be the laser.

Usually, a DVD Writer's lifespan is a lot greater than the warranty, especially in home use, let's say one DVD a week (even though I bet, these days, people are using these things to write data even less).

Anyway, back to your problem. In your case, the root cause might be the dust over the LED of the laser. In this case you just need to clean the laser head with some ear sticks and alcohol.

You can check this on youtube, I think there are a lot of examples of how to clean the laser head (just search for "how to clean a dvd writer").

Let us know if it fixed your problem. If you don't have any luck with this, you might need to buy a new DVD Writer.

Answer (score 0):

Very often you bought a new pack of disks which are all low quality (the stamps making the lines on the disk are worn out when making those, classifying the disks as "class B" products and mostly sold for super-cheap prices in super markets), one failing to be written to successfully after another - it's not the writers fault then. If you buy another pack, your chances are high your writer works flawlessy again.